# Converting swedish charters of a String in Swift

Tags: string, swift

```
var str = "StavsnÃ¤s"
var strWithoutWierdCharacters = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("Ã¤", withString: "ä", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range:nil)
```

There must be a better way of doing this in Swift?

Comment: I haven't used Swift, but this kind of problems have to do with encoding. Try finding a solution to convert from ISO-8859-1 to Unicode.

Comment: Where does the string "StavsnÃ¤s" come from? It is probably better to fix the problem at an earlier point, when the string is created.

Comment: It comes from an API i have no control over... :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that `str` has one *Unicode* character for each *UTF-8 byte* of the
"real" string. For example, the character "ä" (which has the *UTF-8* representation `C3 A4`) is stored as the two Unicode characters "Ã" = `U+00C3` and "¤" = `U+00A4`.

It would be better to fix that problem on the "input side". If that is not possible,
the following trick works as long as all characters in `str` are in the 
range `U+0000 .. U+00FF`:

```
let str = "StavsnÃ¤s"
if let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSISOLatin1StringEncoding) {
    if let fixed = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        println(fixed) // Stavsnäs
    }
}
```

It uses the fact that  `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` maps the Unicode characters
`U+0000 .. U+00FF` exactly to the bytes `00 .. FF`. So "Ã¤" is converted to the bytes
`C3 A4` and these bytes are then interpreted as UTF-8 and converted back to Unicode.